# Assembling a var dynamically

Tags: javascript

How can I assemble a var in Javascript during runtime without eval?

```
var lc = $('.bezeichnung-1').length;
for (var lt = 1; lt <= lc; lt++) {
    eval("var neuerwert"+lt+"=0;"); // this works but I don't want to use it because I read that eval is bad
}


var lc = $('.bezeichnung-1').length;
for (var lt = 1; lt <= lc; lt++) {
    window["var neuerwert"+lt] = 0; // this does not work
}
```

Comment: I have fear that something happens to me if I answer this question

Comment: @svillamayor I also gave up. We can't answer the same questions ten times a day

Comment: @ user: Out of curiousity, do you really want `var lc = $('.bezeichnung-1').length;` (looking up elements with the class `bezeichnung-1` and then using the resulting `length`), as opposed to `var lc = $('.bezeichnung').length-1;` (looking up elements with the class `bezeichnung` and using `length - 1`)? The starting value for `lt` (1) seems odd, too...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I assemble a var in Javascript during runtime without eval?

You don't, but you can make it a property of something.

If these are already at global scope, they're already properties:

```
var lc = $('.bezeichnung-1').length;
for (var lt = 1; lt <= lc; lt++) {
    window["neuerwert"+lt] = 0;
    // -----^ no `var` keyword
}
```

If they're not at global scope (*good for you!*), make them properties of an object, e.g.:

```
var neuerwert = {
    1: /*...value here...*/,
    2: /*....value here...*/
};
```

or an array

```
var neuerwert = [
    /*...value here...*/,
    /*....value here...*/
];
```

and then

```
var lc = $('.bezeichnung-1').length;
for (var lt = 1; lt <= lc; lt++) {
    neuerwert[lt] = 0;
}
```

Note that array indexes start at `0`, so you may have to adjust `lt` if you're using an array.

Comment: I am confused. They were not at global scope already. This is the first time I define them. Yet taking off the `var` works just fine. Why is that?

Comment: @user2164882: *"Yet taking off the var works just fine. Why is that?"* They must be at global scope, or you've assigned them specifically as `window` properties in other code. `window["neuerwert"+lt]` Looks up the property `window["neuerwert"+lt]` on `window`. Globals become `window` properties automatically. You can also add more by doing `window.propName = ...`. But you want to avoid that, the `window` object is overcrowded already.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a var where you should be using an array I believe

```
var lc = $('.bezeichnung-1').length;
var neierwert = ();

for (var lt = 1; lt <= lc; lt++) {
    neuerwert[lt]=0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is bad only in case you pass it an argument that you took from outside.

```
function badEvalExample(varName, varValue) {
    eval("var " + varName + " = " + varValue);
}
```

In this case, the function is vulnerable to erratic/malicious parameters. Your example is perfectly fine, although T.J. Crowder's `window["neuerwert" + lt]` solution is indeed more elegant.

I'd recommend, however, against using variable names like `something1`, `something2`, etc. If you need a list of variables of the same type, then it's better store them in an array: `somethings[0]`, `somethings[1]`, ...

I think the right phrasing for using `eval` is not *it's bad* but rather *it should generally be avoided as long as possible*.